# .htaccess to many parameters in multilang version

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

This is my .htaccess file:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=(de|en|es|fr|nl|pl|ru|se)
RewriteRule ^$/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(de|en|es|fr|nl|pl|ru|se)$  $1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(de|en|es|fr|nl|pl|ru|se)/(.*)$/  $2?lang=$1&%{query_STRING} [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1&g=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

Now, main version without language subdirectory working perfect:

ganted.pl/category/example

$_GET parmeters

```
Array ( [p] => category [id] => example )
```

The problem occurs in language versions:

ganted.pl/en/category/example

$_GET parmeters

```
Array ( [p] => en [g] => category [id] => example )
```

How could I remove the language code, to  not interfere in the $_GET parameters?

ganted.pl/en/category/example should pass the following:

```
Array ( [p] => category [g] => example )
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

Change the last lines in your example

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1&g=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(de|en|es|fr|nl|pl|ru|se)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$2&g=$3&id=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1&g=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

yes, just add the first line above your last one. This should do the trick
If you need it, you can modify my new line to:

```
RewriteRule ^(de|en|es|fr|nl|pl|ru|se)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?lang=$1&p=$2&g=$3&id=$4 [L]
```

so you can use the language parameter too.

Feel free to modify your other lines too ;)

Comment: not working. In this way, I can not pass the third parameter (id).

Comment: @Jarek: Do you have an example when you want to get the id and how the URI looks like?

Comment: http://ganted.pl/ - no parameters | http://ganted.pl/category - [p] | http://ganted.pl/category/example [p][g] | http://ganted.pl/category/example/4 [p][g][id]

Comment: and same for language version: ganted.pl/en/ - no parameters | ganted.pl/en/category - [p] | ganted.pl/en/category/example [p][g] | ganted.pl/en/category/example/4 [p][g][id]

Comment: Live example: ganted.pl/kategoria/karmy_suche and language version ganted.pl/en/kategoria/karmy_suche